# FACEBOOK O-AUTH dialog opening on load automatically

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i have a login page where i will give link for facebook login but unfortunately the facebook oauth dialog opens up as soon as i land on the the login page .I want it on click of the link and not on page load.Can any help?

```
<p><a onclick='login(); return false;'>Login</a></p>
<script>

    // Additional JS functions here
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '3423243443', // App ID
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow server to access session,
            xfbml: true, // enable XFBML and social plugins
            oauth: true // enable OAuth 2.0
            // channelUrl: 'http://www.yourdomain.com/channel.html' //custom channel
        });
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // connected
                alert("connected1"+response.authResponse.expiresIn);

            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // not_authorized
                login();
            } else {
                // not_logged_in
                alert("not logged in");
                login();
            }
        },true);



    };


    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));

    /*function login() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                testAPI(response)
                // connected
                alert("connected2   "+response.authResponse);
            } else {
                // cancelled
                alert("cancelled");
                alert("cancelled"+response.authResponse);
            }
        });
    } ;

    function testAPI() {
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.email + '.');
        });
    }  ;*/


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you inserted the FB.getLoginStatus, which calls your login function, in window.fbAsyncInit on every page's loads.

You should fire FB.getLoginStatus only though a button, with an onclick trigger.

Here is a little example: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/15720747/2212966

Comment: If i do that, that is if i fire using button, how would i make sure that it it would get called only after FB.init() is done doing its part.The issue with keeping it outside is that , i dont get response many times as init () is not yet done.

Comment: I never had this problem, and I'm surprised about it. But you can set a custom true/false variable in it, like this - var fbReady = false; window.fbAsyncInit = function() { ... fbReady = true; } - And create your button trigger. $('#fb-login').on('click', function() { if (!fbReady) return false; ...

Answer (score 0):

I have mine wrapped with a jquery button click event handler. Here is a snippet from my code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

      FB.init({
        appId      : 'my-app-id',//use your facebook appId in here
        status     : false,
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.2'
      });

      jQuery('#signUpWithFacebookButtonId').click(function(){
          FB.login(function(response) {
              if (response.status === 'connected') {
                console.log('Logged into your app and Facebook.');
              } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                console.log('The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.');
              } else {
                console.log('The person is not logged into Facebook, so we are not sure if they are logged into this app or not.');
              }
          }, {scope: 'public_profile, email'});
      });

  };//end window.fbAsyncInit function
```